# how to get previous version rather than updated version in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i made my website in wordpress 3.0.1 version and it work fine but by mistake my wordpress version is updated so site theme is default set so what i can do to get my previous version back?
thank you

Comment: How's your update been done? Through the one-click update button? Normally this won't affect your themes directory...

Comment: Yeah, in Wordpress, updating can be essential from a security perspective. Maybe try to work out the underlying problem to make it work with the updated version

Comment: ya it has been done by one-click update button on deshboard in backend.but my all css change and my custome widget which i made is removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just modified the default theme then I am sorry to have to tell you that your changes have been lost. When WordPress does an update it overwrites the core WordPress files. If you want to create a theme based on the default theme you need to make a copy of the default theme, give it a unique directory name and change the theme details in style.css

eg. If you use twentyten then copy the whole twentyten directory and rename it to a suitable name. Then in style.css find the following lines and change them:

Theme Name: Twenty Ten change to Theme Name: Your Theme Name (same as directory/folder name)

Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/ change to Theme URI: Your site URL

Once the default theme has been overwritten there is no way to undo this.